# Managing labels while migrating from perforce to git

Tags: git, perforce

I am currently into migrating the source code from perforce to git. Along with code, I am also migrating the commit history as well as labels. In perforce, we can select few number of files and attach a label with them whereas in git, a tag is put onto the repository level.

Can anyone suggest a technique which I could use to migrate the perforce label to git?